# MySQL Query for field without a specific word

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a database of electronic items, iphones etc.

I'm trying to sort out the items into individual categories.

I'm sorting each model of phone into their own category.

For Example:
Item: Apple iPhone 5S 16GB Grey, Unlocked B
Category it will be sorted to: Mobile phones > apple > 5s

Item: Apple iPhone 6S 64GB Grey, O2 C
Category it will be sorted to: Mobile phones > apple > 6s

Item: Apple iPhone 6S Plus 16GB Grey, Vodafone B
Category it will be sorted to: Mobile phones > apple > 6s Plus

The trouble I'm having is when I'm searching for just the normal 6S, the results are showing 6S Plus as well.

what query would I run to find the products with the title iphone 6 but exclude the word plus?

Comment: can You show current query so we can help You ?

Comment: Are these the actual strings saved in the database? Could you share your table(s)' structure? It would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Mureinik  
Hi, sorry i'm new to this would you like a screenshot?

Comment: @GadcetLtd the output of `desc mytable` would do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your sorting method there is the brand and the model of an item (iphone 5s in your example).
Create the database and insert some brands.

```
CREATE DATABASE stackoverflow;

CREATE TABLE brand (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  description text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO brand (name, description) VALUES ('apple', 'Apple Mobile Phones', 1);
INSERT INTO brand (name, description) VALUES ('samsung', 'Samsung Mobile Phones', 2);
```

Create a 'model' table :

```
CREATE TABLE model (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  description text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  id_brand int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Note that the Id of the brand Apple could be 1 (created automatically with mysql autoincrement option) if it's the first insert

Insert some models :

```
INSERT INTO model (name, description, id_category) VALUES ('5s', '5s Apple Mobile Phones', 1);
INSERT INTO model (name, description, id_category) VALUES ('5c', '5c Apple Mobile Phones', 1);
INSERT INTO model (name, description, id_category) VALUES ('6', '6 Apple Mobile Phones', 1);
```

And at the end your items:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  description text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  id_model int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO item (name, description, id_model) VALUES ('Apple iPhone 5S', 'Apple iPhone 5S 16GB Grey, Unlocked', 1);
.....
.....
```

id_model and id_brand can be foreign keys.

Selecting the model and the brand of 'Apple iPhone 5S' mobile phones (id=1) :

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, b.name
FROM item a, model b, brand c
WHERE a.id = 1 
  AND a.id_model = b.id
  AND b.id_brand = c.id
```

Result :

```
  'Apple iPhone 5S' | '5s' | 'apple'
```

Filtering all ('5s' | 'apple') mobile phones :

```
SELECT a.name, a.description
FROM item a, model b, brand c
WHERE b.id = 1 
  AND b.id_brand = c.id
```

Result :

```
  'Apple iPhone 5S' | '5s Apple Mobile Phones'
  ........
  ........
```